# "Detail" column not being displayed from List

Tags: sharepoint-designer, list, 2013, xslt, content-query-web-part

I have two lists:

- News
- Events

Both lists contain the following two columns:

- Title (Single line of text)
- Detail (Multiple lines, Plain text)

I am displaying News on News.aspx page using CQWP. It is displaying fine i.e. both Title and Detail are being displayed.

I am displaying Events on Events.aspx page using CQWP but the problem is that only Title is being displayed and not Detail.

This page is the exact copy of News and it uses the same style sheet, but still no luck in displaying Detail. I have double checked that Detail column exists and by the same name.

What do you think could be the reason of it?

Comment: Are both detail columns the same, is it a site column, which has been added to both lists?

Comment: No both are different columns. I mean the name is same "Detail" but both columns are in their respective lists. And by the way I am displaying them using ItemStyle.xsl file. In this file I have defined my own style to display for e.g. <table><tr><td><xsl:value-of select="@Detail"/></td></tr></table>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found out what was causing this and fixed it. When you select your own style from drop down menu in "Presentaion" in CQWP, you also need to define below which fields are you gonna display from your list.
So let's say if you are displaying Title and Detail column from list in ItemStyle.xsl then as soon as you select you style from drop down menu, you will be presented with both fields below with Title field already filled. So you need to define rest of the fields.